# Register fail , Warning: odbc_num_rows() expects parameter 1 to be resource, boolean given in

Tags: php

I'm new to php, I can not make the existing account ckeck work at the time of registration. It worked very well with mssql. But already in php 5.9 it does not work for me. And I have to change to obdc.

The original code was in mssql

```
 <?php
     $infomsg = "";

     if(isset($_POST['register']))
     {
        $date = date('h:i:s a', time());
        $sql_server = "";
        $sql_db = "";
        $sql_user = "";
        $sql_pass = "";                       /// Database Name
        $objConnect = odbc_connect("DRIVER={SQL Server};SERVER=".$sql_server.";DATABASE=".$sql_db.";UID=".$sql_user.";PWD=".$sql_pass.";",$sql_user,$sql_pass);
        $objConnect1 = odbc_connect("DRIVER={SQL Server};SERVER=".$sql_server.";DATABASE=".$sql_db.";UID=".$sql_user.";PWD=".$sql_pass.";",$sql_user,$sql_pass);


          //check query row
        function checkrow($query1)
        {
            if(odbc_num_rows($query1) << 0){
                echo "Username you have entered is already in use!";
            }
            else
            {
              while(odbc_fetch_row($query1)){
              $register = odbc_result($query1,"fdUserNum");
            }
        }
    }

    //security
    function chckifltr($value)//a-z A-Z 0-9 character possible
    {
        if(preg_match('/^[a-z0-9A-Z]+$/i', $value))
        {
            return true;
        }
        else
        {
            return false;
        }
    }
    $username = $_POST['reg_user'];
    $pass1    = $_POST['reg_pass'];
    $pass2    = $_POST['reg_conf_pass'];
    $email    = $_POST['reg_email'];
    $ppass    = $_POST['reg_ppass'];
    if(strlen($username) > 20){
        $infomsg = "<p class=\"bg-danger\">UserID max 20 characters</p>";
    }else{
            if(strlen($email) > 50){
        $infomsg = "<p class=\"bg-danger\">Email max 50 characters</p>";
          }else{
            if(strlen($ppass) > 20){
        $infomsg = "<p class=\"bg-danger\">Second Password max 20 characters</p>";
          }else{
              if(strlen($pass1) > 20){
            $infomsg = "<p class=\"bg-danger\">Password max 20 characters</p>";
              }else{
                  if($username != "" && $pass1 != "" && $pass2 != "")
                  {
                if(chckifltr($username) && chckifltr($pass1) && chckifltr($pass2))
                {
                    if($pass1 == $pass2)
                    {
                      if(checkrow(odbc_exec($objConnect, "SELECT * FROM UserInfoFromPublisher WHERE fdUserID = '".$username."'") == false))
                      { 
                        if(checkrow(odbc_exec($objConnect, "SELECT * FROM UserInfoFromPublisher WHERE fdEmail = '".$email."'") == false))
                    {   
                      $pass3 = md5($pass1);
                      odbc_exec($objConnect, "INSERT INTO UserInfoFromPublisher (fdUserID,fdPassword,fdCash,fdemail,fd2Password) VALUES ('".$username."','".$pass3."',250000,'".$email."','".$ppass."')");
                    $infomsg = "<font color='green'>The account has been successfully made!</p>";
                      }
                      else
                      {
                    $infomsg = "<font color='red'>Email you have entered is already in use!</p>";
                      }
                    }
                    else
                     {
                    $infomsg = "<font color='red'>Username you have entered is already in use!</p>";
                      }
                    }
                    else
                    {
                      $infomsg = "<font color='red'>Passwords don't match!</p>";
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                  $infomsg = "<font color='red'>Please enter only letters and numbers!</p>";
                }
                  }
                  else
                  {
                $infomsg = "<p class=\"bg-danger\">Please fill in all of the fields!</p>";
                  }
                }
            }
        }

    } 
}     
                ?>
```

Warning: odbc_num_rows() expects parameter 1 to be resource, boolean given on line 66

Warning: odbc_fetch_row() expects parameter 1 to be resource, boolean given  on line 71

Answer (score 0):

Ok, wasn't easy but found it!

Take this line:

```
if(checkrow(odbc_exec($objConnect, "SELECT * FROM UserInfoFromPublisher WHERE fdUserID = '".$username."'") == false)){
//Let's break it down.
$query_str = "SELECT * FROM UserInfoFromPublisher WHERE fdUserID = '".$username."'";
$query_result = odbc_exec($objConnect, $query_str);
if(checkrow($query_result == false)){
```

You are passing the result of a condition to checkrow. You are receiving a boolean because of it. I think you just put in inside one too many parentheses.

```
if(checkrow(odbc_exec($objConnect, "SELECT * FROM UserInfoFromPublisher WHERE fdUserID = '".$username."'")) == false){
```